# Upgrading .net entity framework to EF Core seems that base and OnModelCreating are not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have been upgrading from .net 4.6 application to .net core 2.1.x and some of these objects and methods are just not available.

Examples:

1. Issues with `:base("name=mydbentities")`
2. `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`
3. `base:(nameOrConnectionString)`

From the old .net code base are 2 partial classes

```
public partial class OpsCentralEntities : DbContext
{
    public OpsCentralEntities() : base("name=OpsCentralEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

In the above code

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

then this

> 'OpsCentralEntities.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override

Then with the other partial class

```
public partial class OpsCentralEntities : IDbContext
{
    public OpsCentralEntities(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    { }
    ....
}
```

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

Comment: I mean.. .NET core and framework are not on parity.  This is to be expected?

Comment: You are using a new framework, don't expect it to be the same. The constructor now takes `DbContextOptions` or `DbContextOptions<OpsCentralEntities>`

Comment: Entity Framework Core has **many** differences with Entity Framework 6, don't think you can just replace one with the other. Also, EF Core works in .NET Framework while EF6 does not in .NET Core. You only need to use EF Core if you are targeting .NET Core

Comment: Perhaps a better structured question which invites specific answers, rather than what appears to be a request for an article on "how to convert from EF6 to EF Core"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On model creating is available

```
OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) -> OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

Constructor parameter accept options

```
base("name=mydbentities")-> YourContextContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
```

There will be problem if you are using `SqlQuery` because now you need to [add it to model](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862#issuecomment-372889792)

```
modelBuilder.Query<YourModel>() //to OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

db.Query<YourModel>().FromSql(rawSql)
```

And last problem i got was many to many should [be using Extra type](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)